# How to fetch a message from the entire guild

Tags: discord.js

I would like to know how to find a message with its id from the entire guild and not just the current channel.

I have tried

- `message.guild.channels.fetchMessage(message_ID)`
- `client.channels.fetchMessage(message_ID)`
- `message.channel.guild.fetchMessage(message_ID)`
- `message.fetchMessage(message_ID)`
- `message.guild.fetchMessage(message_ID)`

I want it to look through the entire guild and find the message by ID then send what the message has said. Also, I have tried to have it look for the channel that I want the message from but that didn't work either.

If it's possible to get more specific with the code, it should look into a channel called `#qotd-suggestions` with the ID of `479658126858256406` and then find the message there and then send the message's content.

Also, the message_ID part of `fetchMessages` gets replaced with what I say after the command so if I say `!send 485088208053469204` it should send `Message content: "Wow, the admins here are so lame."`

Comment: You can simply do a for loop through all channels and find the message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do that with a `Guild` method, but you can simply loop through the channels and call [`TextChannel.fetchMessage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage) for each of them.
In order to do that, you could use [`Collection.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) but that would be a little more complex if you want to work with vars, so I suggest you to convert [`Guild.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels) to an `Array` with [`Collection.array()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=array).

Here's an example:

```js
async function findMessage(message, ID) {
  let channels = message.guild.channels.filter(c => c.type == 'text').array();
  for (let current of channels) {
    let target = await current.fetchMessage(ID);
    if (target) return target;
  }
}
```

You can then use this function by passing the message that triggered the command (from which you get the guild) and the ID you're looking for. It returns a `Promise<Message>` or, if the message is not found, `Promise<undefined>`. You can get the message by either using `await` or `Promise.then()`:

```js
let m = await findMessage(message, message_ID); // Message or undefined
// OR
findMessage(message, message_ID).then(m => {/* your stuff */});
```